# Which hashing algorithm is used by Neo4J?

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I would like to know which is the hashing algorithm used by Neo4j. In particular, Neo4j Enterprise 4.1.6.

When creating a new user, for example with the command `CREATE USER jack SET PASSWORD 'pass'`, Neo4j will hash and store the password in the `system` database. But what hashing algorithm does it use?

I cannot find it in the official documentation so I looked it up on GitHub. [Here](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/e89ade8beeb5f491c218c67a0d2cfcb1c5a5c2b6/community/cypher/cypher/src/main/java/org/neo4j/cypher/internal/security/SystemGraphCredential.java#L90) is when the password is hashed and [this](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/e89ade8beeb5f491c218c67a0d2cfcb1c5a5c2b6/community/cypher/cypher/src/main/java/org/neo4j/cypher/internal/security/SecureHasher.java) is the class `SecureHasher` used for it. I also see SHA-256 in [this](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/e89ade8beeb5f491c218c67a0d2cfcb1c5a5c2b6/community/cypher/cypher/src/main/java/org/neo4j/cypher/internal/security/SecureHasherConfigurations.java#L31) class but there are two versions. Is it mentioned in the documentation or other documents?

Comment: According to the `SecureHasherConfigurations` class it is either one round of SHA-256 or 1024 rounds of SHA-256. One round means: build the SHA-256 hash of the salt followed by the passwort itself. 1024 rounds means: do one round as above, then calculate 1023 times the SHA-256 hash of the previous result.

Comment: @ThomasKläger thanks for the explanation. I am wondering which mode is used based on what. Would be nice to have this information in the documentation, instead of looking at the code.

Comment: I would expect it to use `SecureHasherConfigurations.CURRENT_VERSION` ("1") if you create a new user and use the older version ("0") only in validating credentials for users that were created with the older version.

Comment: About documenting it: they might think of this as an implementation detail that nobody would need to care about (at least as long as it is sufficiently secure)

Comment: @ThomasKläger all valid points, thanks again. Big banks care about these details for security reasons. Maybe they can't really be compared, but it's easier to find this information for MySQL.

Comment: Anyway, the question is if SHA-256 is used by the specified version of Neo4j. If yes, is this information in an official documentation?